# How can I make static_cast from unique_ptr

Tags: c++, casting, unique-ptr, static-cast

I have the following code, how to cast correctly from unique_ptr to base class?:

```
class MagEventNotifierAndSupplier : public CSubject,
    IMagneticData
{
public:
//implement
}
unique_ptr<MagEventNotifierAndSupplier> m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier;
m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier = make_unique<MagEventNotifierAndSupplier>("test");
IMagneticData* data= static_cast<IMagneticData*>(&m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier);// invalid cast
```

Comment: Have you tried: IMagenticData* dynamic_cast<IMagenticData*> (m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier.get())

Comment: Did you intend to use private inheritance?

Comment: Why dynamic_cast? It's for casting base pointer to a derived one.

Comment: You should be able to get pointer to a base class easily without any explicit casting. Just use get() method of the unique_ptr class.

Comment: 1. IMagneticData* data= m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier.get(); 2. Switch to public inheritance, i.e. class MagEventNotifierAndSupplier : public CSubject,
    public IMagneticData.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `static_cast` a `unique_ptr*` pointer to a `IMagneticData*` pointer, as they are unrelated types.

You don't need a cast at all.  Since `MagEventNotifierAndSupplier` derives from `IMagneticData`, a `MagEventNotifierAndSupplier*` pointer can be assigned directly to an `IMagneticData*` pointer without casting.

You can get a `MagEventNotifierAndSupplier*` pointer from a `std::unique_ptr<MagEventNotifierAndSupplier>` object via its `get()` method, eg:

```
class MagEventNotifierAndSupplier : public CSubject, public IMagneticData
{
public:
    //implement
};

auto m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier = std::make_unique<MagEventNotifierAndSupplier>("test");
IMagneticData* data = m_MagEventNotifierAndSupplier.get();
```